# How to match all locations in nginx, for auth?

Tags: nginx

I need an expression to match all requests, no matter what.

Is this good enough?

```
location ~ ^/
```

I'm worried about other locations taking precedence, bypassing my auth.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can put `ngx_http_auth_basic_module` settings into any of the following contexts:

```
http, server, location, limit_except
```

Your version

```
location ~ ^/
```

Would work only if you don't have another declared locations in your `server` section
example:

```
server {
    ... #some server settings
    location / { # full equivalent for "~ ^/"
        auth_basic on;
        auth_basic_user_file /path/to/some/file;
    }
    location /other_location {
        # here http_auth not inherited
    }
}
```

Just put your `http_auth` settings into `server` section and all locations described for this `server` would inherit this settings.
example:

```
server {
    ... # some server settings
    auth_basic on;
    auth_basic_user_file /path/to/some/file;
    location / {
        # HERE http_auth settings would be
        # inherited from previous configuration level. 
    }
}
```

Comment: The question is how to match all requests to the server. Answer is about how to add basic auth :(

Comment: The question was recently edited, therefore the answer doesn't match